# How to iterate over files in a directory within an extractionless add-on's .xpi file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, thunderbird-addon, firefox-addon-overlay

My add-on, Color Source, needs to iterate files in a directory within my add-on (e.g., the `content` subdirectory) when the add-on is not unpacked (i.e., is kept zipped as an XPI).

We are using code like this to get the Addon object:

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm", null)
        .AddonManager
        .getAddonByID(
            "color_source@brett.zamir",
            function(addon) {
                var uri = addon.getResourceURI();
            }
        );
```

In order to pass a path to `new OS.File.DirectoryIterator`, we have tried:

1. `OS.Path.join(uri.path, 'content');` which apparently works in *nix but not Windows
2. Getting and then cloning `uri.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file`, and then calling `append('content')` on the clone and this works, but only when the add-on has the `<em:unpack>` directive set to true in `install.rdf`.

How do we get a path that works even when the add-on is zipped up?

(Note: I have added a Firefox add-on tag to this post because the issue should be similar there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.xpi` file is a zip file and should be accessed using [`nsIZipReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader).

The following should create a [`nsIUTF8StringEnumerator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIUTF8StringEnumerator) over which you can iterate.  The contents of the zip file which match a pattern are obtained using [`findEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader#findEntries%28%29)

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var zipReader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/libjar/zip-reader;1"]
            .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIZipReader);
var addonFile = new FileUtils.File(uri.path);
zipReader.open(addonFile);
var contentEnumerator = zipReader.findEntries("content/*");
```

This should provide you with all the files and directories which are contained within the `content` directory.  However, you are probably only interested in the files which are directly within the content directory:

```
for(contentFile of contentEnumerator) {
    if(/content\/.*\//.test(contentFile) {
        continue;
    }
    //If you get here contentFile should contain only direct descendants of
    //  the content directory. 
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I hadn't thought of doing that. Was hoping there'd be an easier way, but that isn't too bad, and it's helpful that you've collected it all in one place, thanks! And, I actually need "skin" and subdirectories of "content", but I'm sure I can find my way around now having the API in front of me.

Comment: @Noitidart, I'm not aware of another method to iterate over contents of a directory within a zip file. Reading a file within a zip options:1.[`getInputStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader#getInputStream%28%29) to open [`nsIInputStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIInputStream) read by [`NetUtil.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm);2.[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest);3.etc.